# How to read two seperate sets of information from a text file to a list - PYTHON

Tags: python, list, file, indexing

I have a text file similar to the following. With each line having different types of data:

```
example text 54 bits of example text example text example text example text
0 2 4 3 6 9 5 3 8 9 6 6 5 4 4 5 5
```

It has words on the first line and numbers on the second. 
How can I extract both sets of data into seperate lists. The words in one list, the numbers in another? 
However, the words in the first line may contain numbers so simply stripping words and integers will not work.

Comment: Do you know which line is going to be which?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("data") as f:
    word=filter (None,f.readline().split(" "))
    number=map(float,filter (None,f.readline().split(" ")))
```

read a line and split them in between spaces and store them.

Comment: Will not work because there is numbers in the first line and the first line has to be exactly the same in the list. Please read updated question now.

Comment: what do you want to do with the number in 1st line, do you want to save it as a number or string or just remove that?